# Программа для накрутки лайков

Tags: java, android, c++

Часто встречаю в интернете предложение о накрутке лайков в какой-либо соцсети. 
Может кто знает, на сколько сложно делаются программки такого типа и с чего мне начать?

Просто для дипломной работы хочу взяться делать проект, одной из составляющих которого будет что-то подобное такой программе накрутки лайков и нужно знать сколько примерно уйдёт на реализацию.

Comment: В интернете много чего, знаете ли, предлагают. И не всегда предоставляемое совпадает с обещанным. Для накрутки лайков нужно иметь доступ к аккаунтам, с которых будет происходить накрутка, а также четкое понимание того, как накрутить и при этом "не спалиться". Также не помешает автоматизация процесса накрутки, чтобы не руками заходить на сотни аккаунтов. Для этого нужно уметь залогиниться и поставить лайк либо с помощью API, либо с помощью кликера на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

База ботов/взломанных аккаунтов и работа с API нужной соцсети - все составляющие.

P.S. Работа без научной новизны или инженерной сложности не является дипломной. В приличных заведениях это будет уровень не выше 3.

Comment: зато с этой программы можно получить денег в отличии от абстрактного задания в вакуме) Поэтому актуальность работы вполне прокатит.